# Setting up views - empty means none or empty means all?

Tags: view

I have a large set of data and I need to create specific views of it and display those views to specific user groups.

I am having a disagreement with my dev team on what it means to not specify user groups: is the view available to all or to none, if you don’t specify the user groups?

Please note that this has nothing to do with permissions, is more about displaying relevant data.

A similar question is about the columns that I choose to display on that view: not specifying columns means all columns should be added or none?

Comment: The fact you have disagreement indicates "empty" is ambiguous. Is there a problem using "All" ?

Comment: Exactly – is empty all or nothing? There is not a problem with using all, I just expect that if I don’t specify a user group, that view won’t be visible to everyone…

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an opportunity to improve the experience to before or after you create the view.

- The before-create approach: prompt user whether to share new view with specific team members or everyone. Radio select can be a good design option.
- The after-create approach: your view can initially be saved as private unless you share it with a specific user group or everyone.

In either case, the user retains the freedom to choose, rather than being compelled by app. definition of 'job done' involves user's decision on who to share with otherwise it's not a complete feature in my pov regardless we choose None or All. Let me know if it clarifies.

Comment: It was actually a radio button that saved the day and we agreed to have “All user groups” by default 